# Connected Components in OpenCV 3.4.0 with with cuda (on GPU)

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, connected-components

I wrote a program with c++ and OpenCV 3.4.0 for connected components labeling.

I used `ConnectedComponentsWithStats` function for it. Now I can write same program with OpenCV + cuda. But OpenCV does not have `ConnectedComponentsWithStats` function for cuda.

Somebody said to me that I must use `labelComponents` function for it, but when I write `cv::cuda::labelComponents`, C++ say to me :

`"cv::cuda::" has no member "labelComponents"`

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed in [`cv::cuda:labelComponents`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d5/dc3/group__cudalegacy.html#ga92b4e167cd92db8a9e62e7c2450e4363)

1. Did you compile with legacy support?
2. Did you include the appropriate header file? I believe it is `"opencv2/cudalegacy/cudalegacy.hpp"` See: [cudalegacy.hpp File Reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/da/d10/cudalegacy_8hpp.html)

Comment: No friend. I didn't include "opencv2/cudalegacy/cudalegacy.hpp". But now when I include it from "opencv2/cudalegacy.hpp" and now visual studio show me 113 errors.   Error : Severity Code Description  Project File Line Suppression State Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'cuda_runtime.h': No such file or directory

Comment: That's another issue. Can you compile your project with any `cv::cuda` function at all?

Comment: Yes dear. I can. But when I include "opencv2/cudalegacy.hpp" then occur that problem !

Comment: and I know cuda_runtime.h is in path "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\include" . I added this path to my project but didn't solve my problem

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem with these two steps :

1) Project->Build Dependencies->Build Customisazions...-> Tick CUDA 9.1

2) Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies-> "cudart.lib"